# How to connect ESLint to React project in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webstorm, eslint

After adding to the project ESLint I have error:

> Error: Plugin "react" was conflicted between ".eslintrc.js" and "../.eslintrc".

I'm using WebStorm. In VSCode this works fine.

In details I can see:

```
Error: Plugin "react" was conflicted between ".eslintrc.js" and "../.eslintrc".
    at mergePlugins (/Users/account/Documents/web-km-client/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/config-array/config-array.js:202:19)
    at createConfig (/Users/account/Documents/web-km-client/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/config-array/config-array.js:305:9)
    at ConfigArray.extractConfig (/Users/account/Documents/web-km-client/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/config-array/config-array.js:481:33)
    at CLIEngine.isPathIgnored (/Users/account/Documents/web-km-client/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cli-engine.js:954:18)
    at ESLintPlugin.invokeESLint (/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/languageService/eslint/bin/eslint-plugin.js:100:23)
    at ESLintPlugin.getErrors (/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/languageService/eslint/bin/eslint-plugin.js:78:21)
    at ESLintPlugin.onMessage (/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/languageService/eslint/bin/eslint-plugin.js:52:64)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/jsLanguageServicesImpl/js-language-service.js:105:39)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:329:10)
```

Comment: I am running into the same problem, did you have any luck with that?

Comment: I just deleted project, pulled from git and made npm i

Comment: That's a weird fix but seems to have worked.